# Is safe to publish team-provider-info.json to public repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm a amplify beginner.
When I create amplify project by `amplify init`, `.gitignore` file is automatically create.

This `.gitignore` file is not included `team-provider-info.json`.
But `team-provider-info.json` has ARN and AmplifyAppId.

I don't kwow is it safe to publish `team-provider-info.json` to public repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As like your concerning, AmplifyAppId, AWS Account Id, ARN of resources are written in `team-provider-info.json`. Normally, you *should add* `team-provider-info.json` in `.gitignore` file if you're open-sourcing your project/in public.

`team-provider-info.json` file is used for sharing with team members in the same project to use AWS resources.

Reference: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1779

Comment: Thanks a lot. My suspicion turned clear.